# AWS DynamoDB cross-account access without role assuming

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I've managed to look through some articles of similar questions, but my case is to get responded *list-tables* that are created from another account within the same Organization.

- Account A (within Organization *test*) -> created some tables in
- Account B (within Organization *test*) -> created some tables in
- Account C (within Organization *test*) -> created some tables in
  Question is to get access from EC2 deployed at Account A to DynamoDB tables from accounts A, B, C using

`aws dynamodb --list-tables`

command. I'm not sure if there are some policy-based approaches to specify the access, to that tables.